# How to tell if an NMEA or TAIP sentence is valid

Tags: c#, nmea, taip

The question (which I intend to answer myself in order to selfishly boost my microscopic reputation) is c# code to tell whether or not a given sentence in either NMEA or TAIP format is valid...  essentially calculating what the checksum should be and comparing it with the given checksum, and returning true or false...

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089791/nmea-checksum-in-c-sharp-net-cf)

Comment: Yes, part of my answer credits Carson63000's answer there, but his only covers NMEA messages... my answer (which I can post in 7 hours) will cover TAIP messages as well... helpful for users of the [Utility Rockets](http://www.utility.com/solutions/mobile-appliances0)  which use both formats of messages...

Comment: Fixed question: sentences aren't part of GPS. "Sentences" are part of the communications protocol (such as NMEA or TAIP) used to communicate with *some* (but by no means all) GPS receivers (e.g., those receivers supporting NMEA or TAIP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I came up with...some credit goes to the answer provided by Carson63000 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089791/nmea-checksum-in-c-sharp-net-cf)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsNMEAMessageValid("$GPRMC,102957.92,A,4104.8569,N,00836.4700,W,0.000,5.822,230211,0,W,A*2B").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(IsNMEAMessageValid("$GPRMC,102957.92,A,4104.8569,N,00836.4700,W,0.000,5.822,230211,0,W,A*1B").ToString());   // should be false, changed the checksum from 2B to 1B

        Console.WriteLine(IsTAIPMessageValid(">RPV68168+4008572-0828021400026912;ID=M123;*d<").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(IsTAIPMessageValid(">RPV68168+4008572-0828021400026912;ID=M123;*c<").ToString());    // should be false, changed the checksum from d to c

        Console.WriteLine(IsTAIPMessageValid(">RPV54366+4001403-0828656300005512;ID=GH75;*7c<").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(IsTAIPMessageValid(">RPV54366+4001403-0828656300005512;ID=GH75;*7b<").ToString());    // should be false, changed the checksum from 7c to 7b

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool IsNMEAMessageValid(string sentence)
    {
        // Checksum for NMEA includes XOR on all characters between (not including) the $ and the *, including the commas...
        int checksum = Convert.ToByte(sentence[sentence.IndexOf('$') + 1]);
        for (int i = sentence.IndexOf('$') + 2; i < sentence.IndexOf('*'); i++)
        {
            checksum ^= Convert.ToByte(sentence[i]);
        }
        int givenChecksum = Convert.ToInt16(sentence.Split('*')[1], 16);
        return checksum == givenChecksum;
    }

    private static bool IsTAIPMessageValid(string sentence)
    {
        // Checksum for TAIP includes XOR on all characters starting with > and up to and including *
        int checksum = Convert.ToByte(sentence[sentence.IndexOf('>')]);
        for (int i = sentence.IndexOf('>') + 1; i < sentence.IndexOf('*') + 1; i++)
        {
            checksum ^= Convert.ToByte(sentence[i]);
        }
        char[] splitChars = { '*', '<' };
        int givenChecksum = Convert.ToInt16(sentence.Split(splitChars)[1], 16);
        return checksum == givenChecksum;
    }
}
```